# What word is spoken here?

Tags: phrase-requests

In an episode of Space: 1999, Barbara Bain says a word that sounds like "messagerie" or "mesadry".  In any case I'm not familiar with it.  Could someone identify it for me?  It's at 42:59 in this video:

https://youtu.be/P7d4-DOK_6I?t=42m59s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found by Googling **Space 1999 scripts**:

"Mezadrine", a fictitious drug, presumably.

> 62.INT. COMMAND OFFICE
>
> Helena & Koenig enter through a side door.
>
> HELENA: "**Mezadrine**? That will bring out the most violent,
>   aggressive responses."
>
> KOENIG: "Exactly. And that's just why we have to try it. Helena, if we
>   can summon this creature at a time and place of our own choosing, we
>   might just be able to contain it."

Listed on the scripts site as Season One, Episode 19, rather than Episode 22 as Youtube says.

[Episode script](http://catacombs.space1999.net/main/tscript/z19tts.html)

[List of scripts](http://catacombs.space1999.net/main/tscript/scripts.html)

[Episode plot description on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Troubled_Spirit)